# Automatically convert quotations in the form of "abc" to become ``abc''

Tags: punctuation, quotation

I recently discovered that LaTeX has a different symbol for opening (``` `` ```) and closing (`''`) quotation marks. I have been incorrectly writing `"abc"`. How do I convert all the quotations to become ``` ``abc'' ``` instead? Doing it manually will take forever as I have a lot of quotations.

Comment: You could just use `sed` for this (`sed` is awesome). It does require some escaping on the command line, since you are trying to replace quotes. I can't put it in here, since it contains backticks. So a [link](http://pastebin.com/gLTbYDYi) will have to do.

Comment: On an unrelated note, a lot of editors will automatically replace `"` with the correct quotation form when you type the character. I know for a fact kile does this, and I believe AUCTeX does so as well.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38985/replace-quotes-with-quotes

Comment: @RoelofSpijker There are some advantages in NOT using the auto-replace-feature: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f

Comment: @matth: I completely agree. In my academic writings I (pretty much) never use quotes. The only time I use them is when passing a literal string to the `pgf` math engine and in that case I need actual quotes, not the converted ones. Which mostly ends up in me typing `\"` and then removing the `\`. This doesn't happen often enough for me to disable the autoreplace though. I know what I want in what case and how to obtain it. If you are using mostly quotes as in quotations it's an option though :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An alternative to `quotes` is `csquotes` from 2011, while `quotes` is from 1997 …

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
Hello "World"!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ack, I knew this was too good to be true: `Package csquotes Error: ucs package not supported`

Answer (score 22):

The package [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) has many more goodies than the one mentioned. If you use the command `\enquote{. . .}`, you can nest several levels of quotations, while LaTeX preserves the correct couples of signs. You can even set localization preferences in order to use the proper signs for a language.

For instance, `\enquote{\enquote{This is a quote within a quote}}` will be rendered as:

> “‘This is a quote within a quote’”

(with a thin space in between the contiguous signs).

But if you load the `csquotes` package thus (as I usually do):

```
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=british]{csquotes}
```

the previous code will be rendered thus:

> ‘“This is a quote within a quote”’

See the documentation of the package for further details (`texdoc csquotes`).

Answer (score 11):

There is a package for this: [`quotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quotes).  With this package, `"text"` is typeset correctly as ``` ``text'' ```.

Comment: The package `quotes` is very simplistic. I'd recommend `csquotes` instead.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit 2** solution suggested by Boris seems to be the easier way.

Depending on which editor you use you can perform a search an replace. You would be searching for

```
_"
```

(replace the underscore with a white space, its just there to make my point) and then replace it by

```
_``
```

again, the underscore stands for a white space.

**Edit**

As David Carlisle pointed out that you should also change the right quote to `''` so you get the proper right quote.

However there you have to account for the following characters after the right quote. I know no better way than trying to think of all possibilities (I can think of 4 that are likely)

```
"_ %your quote is followed by a white space
". %your quote is followed by a period
", %your quote is followed by a comma
"! %your quote is followed by an exclamation mark
```

then replace each of them with their respective version

```
''_
```

etc.

**Edit 3** MWE with quotes package

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{quotes}

\begin{document}
\noindent "test" \\
``test''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in addition to changing the left quote to `` ` `` you should change the right one to `''` it is only by accident, and only in some encodings, that the input of `"` produces the right double quote ligature.

Comment: I tried:\usepackage{quotes}   ......  "MyWord" .... but it still making opening curly quote back-ward direction I am using Mac OS X, Standard US english Key-board. I have written full document using TexShop. An did not use underscore...so that I do find and replace as suggested by @Philipp....... Any help please?

Comment: I tried a MWE with the `quotes` package and it works fine. I added the MWE to my answer at the end.