# Using quotation marks

Tags: formatting, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically convert quotations in the form of “abc” to become ``abc"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc)

I have a Microsoft Word document whose text I have copied into a LaTeX `document`.  One of the many changes I need to make before it will look good, is to replace all quotation marks such as

```
"hello"
```

with the LaTeX version

```
``hello''
```

Is there some setting or macro I can define which will tell LaTeX to treat the former quotation marks exactly as it would treat the latter?

Comment: I usually 'fix' this by copying the opening quotes and replacing them with the appropriate LaTeX quote (backticks or two regular quotes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `csquotes`

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
Hello "World"!
\end{document}
```