# Dodgy quotation formatting. Both start quote and end quotes are in the direction of end quotes,

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically convert quotations in the form of “abc” to become ``abc"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc)

My quotes are coming up like end quotes on both sides of the quotation. How can I overcome this?

Here is my code and it works fine on this writer just on my Texmaker the problem happens. Could it be my keymapping or something like this?

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} 
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress, square]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\title{}

\maketitle % Print the title

Some sort of "quotation"

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What other editor are you using? `Version 2.5.1` of `TeXStudio` the `TeXMaker` fork has `Replace double quotes` feature. I don't think this is present in Texmaker yet. The following are possibly duplicate posts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52351/quote-marks-are-backwards-using-texmaker-pdflatex

Comment: I have added `\begin{document}` in your code to make it compilable. I hope you don't mind. `:)`

Comment: @hpesoj626 not at all. Thanks I am not sure which maker it is to be honest. It's whichever the one in the repository from ubuntu 12.10 is. A big buggy actually. Also I think the `\begin{document} should go after the \title{} preamble shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know if we understand each other. So you are saying that you are using another version of Texmaker? I was asking if you are using *another* editor apart from Texmaker. As to where to put the `\title{}` command, I've seen as many cases where it is written in the preamble as it was written after `\begin{document}`. Perhaps we can ask as a separate post. Although I've seen some custom classes that throws errors when it is not written in the preamble and some custom classes that throws errors when it is not written after `\begin{document}`. That said, I don't think I have an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use two backticks

<kbd>`</kbd>

and two

<kbd>'</kbd> to get correct quotes as in

```
``quotation''.
```

Or a better option would be to use `csquotes` package with option

```
 \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
```

as you are using babel.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress, square]{natbib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\maketitle % Print the title

Some sort of ``quotation'' \enquote{quotation}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For  details on `csquotes` refer to documentation which you can get by running `texdoc csquotes` or at [www.texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net).