# Abstract and titlepage

Tags: positioning, titles, abstract

I compile my code and the abstract shows up before the titlepage, but I want it after the title page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Thesis}
\author{by Me}
\date{April 15th, 2013} 


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

stuff and nonsense

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Just call `\maketitle` before environment `abstract` and after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! It really helped and it compiled just the way I wanted it to! Much appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 3):

The following code seems to work well.  `\begin{document}` should be before the title.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\title{Thesis}
\author{by Me}
\date{April 15th, 2013} 


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

stuff and nonsense

\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the placement of `\title`, see question: [Should I place \title, \author, \date in the preamble or after \begin{document}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/92702).

Comment: Oh my god!! Thank y'all so much!! I kept fiddling with it, but couldn't get it to work. I can't believe it's as simple as that. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @izzy If this answer really helped you, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark.