# IEEEtran class: How can I center the title using the two columns option?

Tags: ieeetran

When I compile, I always get the title as part of the left column. I'd like the title to be on the top of the page, bridging across the two columns.

Thanks

Diego

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

%  What ever packages you want to use here.

\begin{document}

\title{Dawn the Mission to Vesta and Ceres}

\author{Dustin~Smith}             

% make the title area                                                               
\maketitle


%\begin{abstract}                                                                   
%\boldmath                                                                          
%The abstract goes here.                                                            
%\end{abstract}                                                                     

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}

Document
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE? Otherwise it's not that helpful to the user since this much comes with the template anyway. Minor nitpick; the author and title should better go into the preamble.

Comment: @percusse I have never had a problem with the title and author in that location.  I added a pic as well.  Plus, I figured the OP had the preamble since the question was about IEEEtran.

Comment: OK I'll wait for your question about it one day.

Comment: Incase you wish to have a good looking output instead of a full screenshot [How does one add a LaTeX output to a question/answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2781/15717)

Comment: @percusse no one has mentioned adverse effects due to not being above the preamble. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument Seems that it is preference and there is a manual that suggest above.

Comment: @texenthusiast I get that because I take screen shots.  I can control the screen shots but I only do that for tikz outputs I show.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument#comment200279_93705

Comment: @percusse I read that.  Joseph Wright said he prefers to put it in the preamble and a comment by David Carlisle said do what works.