# I am having problems with typeset?

Tags: compiling

My document is called introduction.tex. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Identification of potential therapeutic targets in human breast cancer}
\author{myName}
\date{August 2015}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get when I "click" the typeset button on the TexShop interface:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./introduction.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document
class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./introduction.aux) (./introduction.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on introduction.log.
```

I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you! :)

Comment: Add `\maketitle` after your `\date` command.  You might also want to type some text after that ... perhaps something like "Hello World! I'm using \LaTeX{}."

Answer (score 4):

You have not given the compiler anything to publish.  Just put Hi right before the \end to verify this.  And you need to move some content around and add a command for the titlepage as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Identification of potential therapeutic targets in human breast cancer}
\author{myName}
\date{August 2015}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
hi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to have the "[metadata](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/92702/8528)" before `\begin{document}` (for some classes, at least).