# 3.33333pt at the top of the document

Tags: random-numbers, random

I am currently attempting to write my first Latex document and having some issues with it. There is a weird 3.33333pt at the top of the document, as can be seen in the attached image, and it will not go away despite whatever I do. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\lstset{
    frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3,
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

%\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}\HS\HS\HS\HS}%

\begin{document}

\def\HS{\hspace{\fontdimen2\font}}\the\fontdimen2\font
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\title{Paper}
\author{
    Author One\\
    \texttt{author.one@email.com}
    \and
    Author Two\\
    \texttt{author.two@email.com}
}
\date{Docs version: 1.0.0\\\today}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{paper_title}}
\maketitle

\newpage
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you use `\the\fontdimen2\font` (which outputs something at the top)?

Answer (score 9):

It comes from `\the\fontdimen2\font` placed immediately after `\def\HS{\hspace{\fontdimen2\font}}`, so just remove that.

You might also want to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. The latter will silently overwrite any existing macro, if the macro name (here `\HS`) was used before. Hence, if you're a bit unlucky/careless with the choice of macro name, you might end up breaking the document some way or another. `\newcommand` on the other hand checks if the macro is already defined, and throws an error if that is the case. (See also [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand) for a lot of info about the difference between the two.)

Unrelated: I'd also move the colour definitions to the preamble, possibly along with `\title`/`\author`/`\date` (see [Should I place \title, \author, \date in the preamble or after \begin{document}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\lstset{
    frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3,
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

%\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}\HS\HS\HS\HS}%

% \newcommand instead of \def here
\newcommand\HS{\hspace{\fontdimen2\font}}%\the\fontdimen2\font
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\title{Paper}
\author{
    Author One\\
    \texttt{author.one@email.com}
    \and
    Author Two\\
    \texttt{author.two@email.com}
}
\date{Docs version: 1.0.0\\\today}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{paper_title}}
\maketitle

\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this works great! Thank you also for your feedback (:

Comment: I'd suggest `\newcommand` instead of `\def`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, good point, I've edited.

Comment: @DanielPacheco See egreg's comment, and my edited answer.