# Wrong direction of quotation marks

Tags: punctuation

How to change the direction of quote mark in latex?
Both of them are in same direction.  How to have one in opposite direction?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{iiscthes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagestyle{bfheadings}
\title{Introduction}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{One}
\subsection{One-One}
\textbf{''More--than--Moore"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Quote marks are backwards (using texmaker/PDFLatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52351) and also [Automatically convert quotations in the form of "abc" to become \`\`abc"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50712)

Comment: You can configure editors to convert these directly for you. For example, TeXnicenter does that.

Comment: if you are looking for the correct quotation based on your country, [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) has options to set up different quotation styles. It can be changed globally or within a document, e.g. `\setquotestyle{french} \enquote{Quoted text}`.

Comment: Another vote for `csquotes`. I could never be bothered with „the LaTeX way” of entering them (i.e. double backticks: I use them as a dead grave accent keys and they are hard to reach to begin with, so not a great option), so short of entering appropriate quotation marks directly, `csquotes` probably works best. It takes care of proper nesting, too, which is icing on the cake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the <kbd>`</kbd> key twice, instead of double quotes, i.e.

```
``More--than--Moore''
```

It is on the same key as <kbd>~</kbd> on American keyboards.

Comment: Its not working..

Comment: @user87834 if it is not working then you have incorrect input, but you have not shown what input you have used, so it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: The code is attached.

Comment: @user87834 you are not writing what SSL is, you end start with ``''`` two apostrophs and end with a quote mark. That is not what SSL wrote

Answer (score -2):

A work-around (though I'm sure some will criticize) is to use reflectbox

\reflectbox{''}More-than-More''

Comment: This doesn't orient the open quotes correctly.  The orientation would be correct if they were rotated 180 degrees, but that's still not the right way to do it.