# Using \selectlanguage with csquotes

Tags: punctuation, babel, csquotes

As [per this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc), I am using `csquotes` to convert quotationmarks to typographical-quotes. However, when changing language through `\selectlanguage` the quotationmarks no longer gets converted. (I need an English abstract and Danish content. Instead of renaming the abstract I find it “prettier” to change language before and after the abstract, though it’s more cumbersome.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage[danish=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}    
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{danish}
Quote: "Morbi dolor risus."
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I leave `\selectlanguage{danish}` out (Danish already is the active language) it works for me. Selecting Danish probably makes `"` a `babel` shorthand a thus overwrites the `csquotes` definition.

Comment: That might be it. Unfortunately I have already used a `\selectlanguage{english}` for the abstract and need to revert back to Danish. I could remove both and rename the abstract-title but that doesn't feel like the right way to do this.

Comment: If you only need English for the abstract you could try putting it into `\begin{otherlanguage*}{english} ... \end{otherlanguage*}` instead of using `\selectlanguage` (I haven't tested this, though)

Comment: That does indeed work and I might go with it. Of course I'd still love a solution to this problem in case anyone else needs a solution to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\EnableQuotes` to get the quotes back. But I personally prefer the `\MakeAutoQuote` command with an non-ascii arguments:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle, %if quote style should change with language
           danish=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}   
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{danish}
\EnableQuotes
"Quote" 

danish Quote: «Morbi «dolor» risus.»

\selectlanguage{english}
\EnableQuotes
"Quote" 

english Quote: «Morbi «dolor» risus.»
\end{document}
```