# Package csquotes does not seem to work within a mdframed box defined via a macro

Tags: macros, mdframed, csquotes

If I define a macro which uses a [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) box, this seems to disable [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)  (red box). But using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) directly (i.e., without defining it via a macro), then [the `csquotes`  package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) can do its job just fine (green box).

[image]

How can I define an [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) environment within a macro *and* also use the nice features of [the `csquotes`  package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)?

### References:

- [Automatically convert quotations in the form of "abc" to become ``abc"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\mdfsetup{frametitlerule=true, frametitlerulecolor=brown}

\newcommand{\HelloWorld}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red!25,frametitle={Usage of mdframed via a macro (Quotes Are Incorrect)}]
        "Hello World."
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}

\HelloWorld

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!25,frametitle={Direct usage of mdframed (Quotes Are Correct)}]
    "Hello World."
\end{mdframed}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations for your 100K!

Comment: I second egreg's comment: congrats!

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I thought I'd have it a long time ago, but had to force my self to do some "real" work. :-)  Congratulations on your imminent 300K!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `csquotes` performs `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` by making `"` active, but it postpones the setting `\AtBeginDocument`. So, when your `\newcommand{\HelloWorld}{...}` is processed, the `"` characters in the replacement text are normal (non active) characters.

If you try adding `\show` before the first `"` in the definition, compilation will stop with

```
> the character ".
\HelloWorld ...ro (Quotes Are Incorrect)}] \show "
                                                  Hello World." \end {mdframed}
```

If you add `\show` before `"` in the “naked” `mdframed` environment, you'll get

```
> "=macro:
->\csqQQ {34}.
l.23     \show"
               Hello World."
```

(and several errors, of course).

So `mdframed` has nothing to do with this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\mdfsetup{frametitlerule=true, frametitlerulecolor=brown}

\newcommand{\HelloWorld}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[
      backgroundcolor=red!25,
      frametitle={Usage of mdframed via a macro (Quotes Are Correct)}
    ]
        \csqQQ{34}Hello World.\csqQQ{34}
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}

\HelloWorld

\begin{mdframed}[
  backgroundcolor=green!25,
  frametitle={Direct usage of mdframed (Quotes Are Correct)}
]
    "Hello World."
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So should I just use `` instead for anything before `\begin{document}` instead of `\csqQQ{34}`, or is there an advantage to using `\csqQQ{34}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I see no advantage, it was just to show that the emulation is working.

Answer (score 4):

If your `\newcommand{\HelloWorld}` is the last activity before `\begin{document}` and there are no anothers `"` in your real code, you should prepend before this command:

```
\catcode`\"=13
```

and you needn't to change your definition.

The reason was answered by egreg. You need to have the `"` active at the time of definition of the `\HelloWorld`.

Comment: Yeah that works, but only if I set the `\catcode` _outside of `\newcommand`. Would have used this solution if I could put this _inside_ the `mdframed` environment.

Comment: catcodes are used during tokenization process, i.e. when TeX reads text from *file*. No from macro. Tokens are stored to the macro body and they are never changed (exceptions exist). If you really need to do re-tokenization during macro processing, you can try to use `\scantokens` primitive from eTeX.