# Initial 'single quote' is backwards - csquotes

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, quoting, csquotes

Should I be using *fontspec* per [Single quotes in csquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137210/single-quotes-in-csquotes)
[image] ?  My initial single quote faces the wrong way, latex thinks it's an apostrophe.

MWE: filename: mwe-singlequotes.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,hebrew,british,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,polyglossia,fontspec,csquotes,setspace}
\geometry{vscale=.85} %default is .7, bottom margin too big
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,labeldate]{biblatex-chicago}
%makes block quotes single spaced
\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
{\begin{spacing}{1}\quote}
{\endquote\end{spacing}}
\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}
\SetBlockThreshold{0}
\begin{document}
\section*{Initial 'single quote' is backwards}
\doublespace
I am having trouble with, "single quotes, said the 'latex user' to his     'friend.'"  
The first one is back wards.  \texthebrew{".הראשון הוא חזרה מחלקות"}  Oh no, I just discovered that Hebrew quotes are wrong.  Let me try this "\texthebrew{הוא}"  Ok, that's a 'stopgap'

\blockquote{I reached a point towards the end on the old heart where I had trouble getting out of a chair. All I wanted to do was get out of bed in the morning and walk to my office and sit back down in the chair. Now I throw 50 pound bags of horse feed in the back of my pickup truck and I don't even think about it. I'm back doing those things.}

Well I don't know when to use blockquote vs. displayquote.  Please don't try to fix my backward initial single quote by putting me on babel/pdflatex instead of polyglossia/xelatex.  I think I'm on csquotes insteads of quotes or quoting for a reason, but I don't know it any more.  This document compiles with \$latexmk -xelatex -f mwe-singlequotes.tex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, problem is actually somewhat related to auto-complete (auto-close?) features in SublimeText.  I was hitting single quote ' and being given two ' ' with the cursor placed in between.  This makes the first one backwards after compilation.  By hitting ` instead I am actually given ` ' with the cursor in between and it compiles to correctly to pretty-curly-single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "inverted" when you start a single quote part should work:

> `text'

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,hebrew,british,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,polyglossia,fontspec,csquotes,setspace}
\geometry{vscale=.85} %default is .7, bottom margin too big
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,labeldate]{biblatex-chicago}
%makes block quotes single spaced
\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
{\begin{spacing}{1}\quote}
{\endquote\end{spacing}}
\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}
\SetBlockThreshold{0}
\begin{document}
\section*{Initial `single quote' is backwards}
\doublespace
I am having trouble with, "single quotes, said the `latex user' to his     `friend.'"  
The first one is back wards.  \texthebrew{".הראשון הוא חזרה מחלקות"}  Oh no, I just discovered that Hebrew quotes are wrong.  Let me try this "\texthebrew{הוא}"  Ok, that's a `stopgap'

\blockquote{I reached a point towards the end on the old heart where I had trouble getting out of a chair. All I wanted to do was get out of bed in the morning and walk to my office and sit back down in the chair. Now I throw 50 pound bags of horse feed in the back of my pickup truck and I don't even think about it. I'm back doing those things.}

Well I don't know when to use blockquote vs. displayquote.  Please don't try to fix my backward initial single quote by putting me on babel/pdflatex instead of polyglossia/xelatex.  I think I'm on csquotes insteads of quotes or quoting for a reason, but I don't know it any more.  This document compiles with \$latexmk -xelatex -f mwe-singlequotes.tex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm typing mostly in sublime text on a mac.  It's a monospaced font that makes all quotes look like straight quotes not curly quotes.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50711/backward-opening-quote-in-mac  suggests TeXShop does some magic to your quotes as you type them.

Comment: Is your "inverted"  the backtick under the tilde?  ~ ?  So I should open all single quotes with a back tick?

Comment: @paynito I use an azerty keyboard. In this case it done with `alt gr + 7`. On other keyboard I don't know

Answer (score 3):

Your outer quotes work because of the `\MakeOuterQuote` declaration. You can make a similar declaration for the inner quotes, but you can't use `'` as `csquotes` protects it (you would run into problems with apostrophs). The "accent aigu" would work, but I would prefer to use the csquotes commands

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeInnerQuote{´}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\begin{document}
I am having trouble with "single quotes, said the ´latex user´ to his friend"

I am having trouble with \enquote{single quotes, said the \enquote{latex user} to his friend}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a backtick like suggested by Romain will give the correct quote too but doesn't make use of the csquotes features and don't adapt when you change the language.

Comment: c'mon it's only an accent aigu or accent grave on top of a letter, by itself it's a backtick, like (forward) slash and backslash, computer words must follow American usage Q.E.D.

Comment: @paynito: I know that the grave accent is called backtick when used alone, But I have no idea how the accent aigu is called. And if you only want answers from native americans, I don't mind to ignore you in the future.

Comment: You should be able to type both accents alone by hitting space instead of some char after option-e, at least that is how it works on my keyboard.

Comment: \`h' can be <option-e> <spacebar> h ' _or_ <option-e> h ' the 2nd would give é' not \`e' so I'm leaning toward ` as \openSingleQuote and → to exit the auto-closed single quotes.